# First Post review instructions are mislabeled

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-queue

When reviewing "First Posts", the instructions provided say that I am reviewing a first *question*, even though I'm reviewing a first *answer*.

If the system cannot be made to intelligently change the text, I suggest that the language be made more universal (e.g. 'first post').

[image: question/answer screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like questions are being mislabeled as answers too. Someone has already posted this on Meta.SO. You can follow the action [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/213292/172958)